# Private Key copied to new Server still asks for password

Tags: linux

We are migrating from a Solaris server to a Redhat server.  My customer has copied the public key of old solaris server to his LDAP server and wants the Private Key of the Solaris Server to be copied to the new RedHad Server and do the password less login.

Note that there is no IP connectivity between New RedHat server and old Solaris server, so I copied the private key of the Solaris server to my local machine and then uploaded it to the Redhat server.  After copying the private key, when I try to login to the host server I am still asked for a password.

What am I doing wrong here?  Here is the file permission on the copied files:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 mycom mycom  401 Jan 19 14:33 id_rsa.pub
-rw-------. 1 mycom mycom 1679 Jan 19 14:33 id_rsa
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix Stackexchange! You can [take the tour first](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) and the learn [How to Ask a good question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to do. Where are you trying to log on? On which server? From which machine? If you are trying to log on the new ldap server, why do you have the private key on that server?

Comment: Hi Andcoz,
We have 2 servers, Sol-A is a solaris server and Server-B another Server(don't know OS). 
Sol-A has to copy files from Server-B, without using password.
Sol-A is decommissioned gradually, new RedHat Server say RH-A is commissioned to replace Sol-A.
Customer network has Public key stored on centrally located LDAP server, associated with the user account, this allows it to be changed in one place and authentication to any of the servers can be done via LDAP.
I have to configure password-less authentication and tried copy private key of Sol-A to RH-A, but still asked for password.

Comment: Have you checked if both private keys are the same? Have you checked if your config forces password authentication?

Comment: Hi YoMismo, how to check config enforcement for password authentication.

Comment: I am new to Linux and need help to migrate private key from one server to another server.